# explains shows fast execution time, but running the query never returns

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, explain

I have a query that seems to never return.
When I run `explain` on that query, it shows me `executionStats.executionTimeMillis` of 27ms, and that the initial input-stage is `IXSCAN` that should return 4 objects only.
I've confirmed that querying for the input-stage query returns only 4 results.

This is my query:

```
{"$or":[
    {"field1.key":{"$in":["name1","name2",/^prefix.*suffix$/]},"field2.key":"foobar"},
    {"field1.key":{"$in":["name1","name2",/^prefix.*suffix$/]},"field3.key":"foobar"}
]}
```

This is the `explain({ verbose : "executionStats" })` output (sorry for the long paste):

```
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "mongosPlannerVersion" : 1,
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "SHARD_MERGE",
            "shards" : [ 
                {
                    "shardName" : "...",
                    "plannerVersion" : 1,
                    "indexFilterSet" : false,
                    "parsedQuery" : { ... },
                    "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "SUBPLAN",
                        "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "OR",
                            "inputStages" : [ 
                                {
                                    "stage" : "FETCH",
                                    "filter" : {"field1.key":{"$in":["name1","name2",/^prefix.*suffix$/]},
                                    "inputStage" : {
                                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                        "keyPattern" : { "field3.key" : 1.0 },
                                        "indexName" : "field3.key_1",
                                        "isMultiKey" : true,
                                        "isUnique" : false,
                                        "isSparse" : false,
                                        "isPartial" : false,
                                        "indexVersion" : 1,
                                        "direction" : "forward",
                                        "indexBounds" : {
                                            "field3.key" : [ "[\"foobar\", \"foobar\"]" ]
                                        }
                                    }
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "stage" : "FETCH",
                                    "filter" : {"field1.key":{"$in":["name1","name2",/^prefix.*suffix$/]},
                                    "inputStage" : {
                                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                        "keyPattern" : { "field2.key" : 1.0 },
                                        "indexName" : "field2.key_1",
                                        "isMultiKey" : true,
                                        "isUnique" : false,
                                        "isSparse" : false,
                                        "isPartial" : false,
                                        "indexVersion" : 1,
                                        "direction" : "forward",
                                        "indexBounds" : {
                                            "field2.key" : [ "[\"foobar\", \"foobar\"]" ]
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "rejectedPlans" : []
                }, 
                ...
                // same plan for the 3 other shards
                ...
            ]
        }
    },
    "executionStats" : {
        "nReturned" : 0,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 27,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 4,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 4,
        "executionStages" : {
            "stage" : "SHARD_MERGE",
            "nReturned" : 0,
            "executionTimeMillis" : 27,
            "totalKeysExamined" : 4,
            "totalDocsExamined" : 4,
            "totalChildMillis" : NumberLong(63),
            ...
            // execution times for each shard
            ...
        },
        "allPlansExecution" : []
    },
    "ok" : 1.0
}
```

**UPDATE**

It seems that despite `explain` mentioning it uses `"field2.key"` for the first part of the `$or` and `"field3.key"` for the second part of the `$or`, when looking at `db.currentOp().inprog` it shows:
`"planSummary": "IXSCAN { field1.key: 1.0 }, IXSCAN { field3.key: 1.0 }"`
so it selected the wrong index for one of the `$or` parts, and thus making the query scan a huge number of documents.

1. Any idea why `explain` gets the indexes right, but the query itself doesn't?
2. How can we `hint` mongo to use the correct indexes, when using `$or`?

Comment: Do you see the query in `db.currentOp().inprog`? What does the `planSummary` field contain in the relevant op object there?

Comment: @Meni thanks! this helped me to better understand the issue

Comment: Could you find a solution? I think I've got the same problem here. The explain query returns almost instantly and the `winningPlan` is the correct index, but the query takes for ever to execute. The `db.currentOp().inprog` does not have the `planSummary` attribute.